# How to run vim command silently without interrupting bash script

Tags: bash, vim

I run the following vim search-and-replace command within a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
...
vim -c ':%s/candle/light/g | write | quit' file.txt
...
```

The command above opens a file, replaces every 'candle' with 'light', save and quit.

The problem is that when no word 'candle' is found within that file, the whole script is interrupted. And I can see vim saying:

`E486: Pattern not found: candle`

How can I run the command silently without interrupting the bash script?

Comment: 1. `sed` is better indicated for that kind of usage than Vim. 2. If you absolutely insist on using Vim for this, then you should consider learning a bit more about substitutions. See `:help :s`.

Comment: Thanks. The needed flag is e in addition to g.